# How to register for IClipboardStatics event via WRL

Tags: c++-cx, wrl

I can get an IClipboardStatics via:

```
ComPtr<IClipboardStatics> clipboard;
HRESULT hr = GetActivationFactory(HStringReference(RuntimeClass_Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_Clipboard).Get(), &clipboard);
```

But how do I call add_ContentChanged()? Not sure how to pass my lambda function?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The question is asking about WRL, but the only tag present is [tag:c++-cx]. Are you looking for a solution using WRL or C++/CX?

Comment: WRL tag added, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution via this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160629-00/?p=93775).

```
auto handler = Callback<IEventHandler<IInspectable*>>(
    [](IInspectable*, IInspectable*)
    {
      // do stuff
      return S_OK;
    });

  clipboardStatics->add_ContentChanged(handler.Get(), &regtoken);
```